# How to choose the previous id from the last id with PDO

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, limit

I want to choose the previous id from the last id. How can I do it?
Database is mysql.

example:

```
id name
1   asd
2   adas
3   ads
4   dsf -> I want to choose this 
5   rew

id name  ---------------------------------------|
1   asd                                         |
2   adas                                        |
3   ads                                         |
4   dsf                                         |
5   rew -> I want to choose this if I add any "name"
6   zxc
```

I tried this lines so far:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM answerController ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetch();
```

Comment: Note that there is a manual for this kind of stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the `offset` for the `limit` to start at.

```
SELECT * FROM answerController ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 2
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

> the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

So it should be:

```
$sql = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM answerController ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1, 2");
$sql->execute();
$data = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $data['name'];
```